# PHP upgrade not allowing uploads

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I have been running Sentora web hosting control panel for almost a year now and everything has been working perfectly.

I recently installed Wordpress in order to set it up as an intranet. The theme I used had some plugins that required PHP 5.6+. I was running PHP 5.5 so I upgraded it (via Ubuntu 14.04).

Now in WP I keep getting "Missing a temporary folder" when trying to upload images.

With WP I tried to manually setup a temp folder by creating a php.ini file in the root of WP and a temp folder which did not work:

```
upload_tmp_dir = /temp/
```

and I tried by adding the following code in wp-config.php and creating the temp folder:

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/temp/');
```

So I checked my other sites that were previously running and noticed that my Help Desk (HESK) will no longer let users upload attachments.

I think something went wrong with the upgrade of PHP and I am not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a permissions problem.

From HESK /readme.html file...

> set modify/write/read permissions for file hesk_settings.inc.php and directory attachments.

Probably the same sort of issue for Wordpress, but I don't know where to look for that.

'upload' and 'tmp' folders typically need 755 permission so things can be written there.  The software should then take the uploaded files and put them away securely.